# What does this tcl script achieve by creating a pipe to ls?

Tags: tcl

Here is the script:

```
# Announce intent
puts "\nOpening a Pipe\n"

# and open a pipe to the ls command
set pipe [open "|ls /" "r"]

# Equivalent command under MS-Windows is:
# set pipe [open "!command.com /c dir" "r"]
# read the output of the ls command:

while {![eof $pipe]} {
  set length [gets $pipe lsLine]
  puts "$lsLine is $length characters long"
}
```

I do not understand what it is piping the ls into? The ls is not a file so I do not understand what is happening here.

The returned data looks like this:

```
bin is 3 characters long
cygdrive is 8 characters long
Cygwin.bat is 10 characters long
Cygwin.ico is 10 characters long
Cygwin-Terminal.ico is 19 characters long
dev is 3 characters long
etc is 3 characters long
home is 4 characters long
lib is 3 characters long
proc is 4 characters long
sbin is 4 characters long
tmp is 3 characters long
usr is 3 characters long
var is 3 characters long
 is -1 characters long
```

Comment: The `-1` is the could-not-read-anything indicator from `gets $channel varName`, which on a blocking channel only ever means end-of-file.

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and the better alternative of tcl's built in `glob` command.

Comment: Also, didn't you ask earlier about the point of the comparison in `while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {}`? Your last line of output is why you see that being used.

Answer (score 2):

That's a *read-only* pipeline — notice the (optional) `"r"` afterwards — and is not a pipe into so much as a pipe *out of*. What it does is create a Tcl channel that the output of `ls /` can be read from. In fact, it does the same thing that `exec ls /` does, except it wraps the result as a channel instead of reading it all and producing the string. The leading `|` in there is just a special indicator character to say “make a pipeline”. (Your comment about Windows is slightly wrong; `!` has no special meaning, and `|` has its usual special meaning on that platform.)

Note that Tcl handles pipelines rather well, in that on *all platforms* you can do asynchronous I/O with them (including using them with notifiers, the mechanism behind `fileevent`) and this is particularly noticeable with bidirectional pipelines (which do have a bunch of gotchas, but they're not actually Tcl's fault). But you've got the simple read-only case in blocking mode, and are just reading whole lines.

---

When the output is fairly small and you're just reading everything in, it's definitely a bit easier to use `exec …` instead of `open |…`.

Also, if you're just interested in listing the contents of a directory, use Tcl's built in `glob` command.